# Pycharm интерфейс

Tags: pycharm, virtualbox

Использую Virtualbox 7.0.10, Ubuntu 22. в Pycharm интерфейс будто недогружен до конца. Может кто-то сталкивался? Переустановка Ubuntu не помогает. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

[image: кнопки]
[image: кнопки]

Comment: Может так и задумано?